# Sets and ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, loops, foreach, set

I have a for each loop with a Set type.

While I loop through this Set I add elements to it.

```
 for (Object o: Set) {
    //i do something and add to the set
  }
```

I keep getting the `ConcurrentModificationException`. But I don't know how I would go about adding to this `Set` that wouldn't cause this exception. I can't create a new for each loop that wouldn't work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera: Iterators allow for *removal* of values, but not *addition* as far as I'm aware.

Comment: What do you mean by "I cant create a new for each loop that wouldnt work" - what exactly wouldn't work, and in what way wouldn't it work? I'd normally just build up a collection of "things to add afterwards" and add them afterwards...

Comment: What I mean is I need to use the exact same set and continuously update it. But I cant seem to figure out how to do it?

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera: You think incorrectly.

Comment: What you're trying to do is generally impossible with the standard collections. However, if you could elaborate a bit more, there might be a specific solution to your problem.

Comment: A common way of doing this is to create a new set, and add to that while iterating over the original.

Comment: I am collecting items into a set which I am concurrently iterating through. Basically it will keep collecting info until there is no more info then eventually the lopp will stop. But i have to do this in the same loop. ArrayLists worked just fine but Im gathering huge amounts of data?

Answer (score 2):

You need to either

- use a Set which doesn't trigger a ConcurrentModifcationException e.g. ConcurrentXxxSet
- take a copy of the set before altering it.

The simplest change is

```
for (Object o: set.toArray()) {
    if (condition(o))
       set.add(something);
}
```

With generics a simpler solution might be

```
Set<T> set = 
for(T t: new HashSet<T>(set)) {
   // something which might add to set
}
```

Note: this will prevent it iterating over elements you just added.
Note2: using the concurrent sets may result in you seeing added elements or possibly not.

If you really need to see elements as you add them you need to use a list, possibly instead, or as well.

```
List<T> list = new ArrayList<>(set);

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    T t = list.get(i);

    if (condition)
        // if it is not a duplicate
        if (set.add(something))
            list.add(something);
}
```

This will allow you to see elements you have added in the loop in a reliable manner.  Note: some care needs to be take to not create an infinite loop and run out of memory.

An alternative is to use a queue instead of a list.  This might be nicer, but I suspect less efficient.

```
Queue<T> q = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>(set);

for(T t : q) {
    if (condition)
        // if it is not a duplicate
        if (set.add(something))
            q.add(something);
}
```

Comment: How much less efficent is the queue? I am handling large amounts of data hence the reason I want to use a Set?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a temporary  `Set` and add your elements to this temp Set, and when you finished lopping over all elements, add the values from the temp Set to the original Set

Example:

```
Set<Integer> originalSet;
//stuff where you fill your original Set
Set<Integer> tempSet = new Set<Integer>();

for(Integer i : originalSet) {
    tempSet.add(<integerToAdd>);
}
originalSet.addAll(tempSet);
```

Comment: But how do I keep looping through the  originalSet? I dont want it to stop

Comment: what do you mean with keep looping? it will keep looping through all items in your originalSet. Or should it also loop through the items which I add to the tempList?

Comment: Yes it also needs to loop through the items in the temp list as well and keep going till no more items are added? Works fine with arraylists trying to get it to work with sets

Comment: So, why would you like to use a Set?

Comment: Efficency and speed :)